# Error during String declaration

Tags: c, string

Why does

```
char line[10] = "1234";
```

work fine but

```
char line[10];
line = "1234";
```

throws an

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line works because it performs an initialization of the `char` array with data. It would be the same as:

```
char line[10] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
```

In the second example, the type of `"1234"` is `const char*`, since it is a pointer to a constant `char` array. You're trying to assign a `const char*` to a `char*`, which is illegal. The correct way to assign a constant (or other) string to a string variable is to use `strcpy`, `strncpy`, or any other string handling function.

Comment: This is wrong. The example is not trying to assign as `const char *` to a `char *`. The minor error is that string literals, despite being non-modifiable, have type `char *`. The major error is that the left-hand side `line` does not have type `char *`, it has type `char [10]`. Arrays are not pointers. In this situation, `line` is a non-modifiable lvalue, but that's rather irrelevant since no matter what you put on the righthand side, it can't have type `char [10]` (because arrays decay to pointers in non-lvalue context) and thus the types can never match.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are not pointers. In your second example, `line` is a non-modifiable lvalue, but more importantly, no matter what you put on the righthand side, it can't have type `char [10]` (because arrays decay to pointers in non-lvalue context) and thus the types can never match.

For what it's worth, a string literal has type `char [N]`, not `const char [N]` and especially not `const char *`, despite the fact that attempts to modify it invoke undefined behavior. (Here `N` is the length of the quoted text in bytes, including the added null terminator.)

Comment: Technically I believe the same conversion from "array of type" to "pointer to type" occurs to the left hand operand of the assignment operator as well, so the two sides *can* have the same type; but the since the left hand operand is not an lvalue the contraints of the assignment operator have been broken.

Comment: It doesn't. The "decay" to pointer happens everywhere *except* the LHS of assignments and the operand of `sizeof`.

Comment: The exact text in C99 is: *Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array,...* - which doesn't include the LHS of assignments.  Note that the prior paragraph, applying to lvalues that do *not* have array type, explicitly lists the LHS of assignment operators, so the omission of this case when discussing arrays is notable.

Comment: So it decays, and then the LHS is a non-lvalue expression of type `char *`? If so, then the error the compiler is giving seems to be an incorrect description of what's wrong with the code, and the correct error would be that the LHS is not an lvalue.

Comment: Yes, the standard seems to be pretty clear - which would make it wrong for the same reason that `1 = 2` is wrong.

Comment: Rather I would say it's wrong for the same reason `(int)x = 1;` or `((char *)voidp)++;` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because those are the rules of the language, as others have explained. I'd write it like this though and avoid declaring up-front how many characters there are.

```
const char* line = "1234";
```